# Should UUIDFields be made unique and indexed in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, uuid

I have a model which has a `UUIDField`, that is not the primary key. The primary key is simply left as the default, a big integer field.

```
import uuid

class MyModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(_('uuid'), default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Now my question is, should I explicitly declare the field to be unique? I realize the chance of collisions is very very small, which is probably why the Django documentation does not explicitly make the field unique. Also, should I also index the field in the database? Like so:

```
import uuid

class MyModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(_('uuid'), default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, db_index=True)
```

The field will mostly be used as an external identifier, where the id is generally not preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a unique identifier, but you seem to be letting Django do its default thing and, separately, using a UUID for services accessing this system. That's redundant. Just set [`primary=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#primary-key) on the UUID field and make it your PK (which implies `unique=True`).

If a record needs to be accessible based on any field, *you need to declare that field unique.* UUIDs can collide, and while the chance is somewhere between very low and negligible, it's not zero; considering the very low cost of coding around that case, you owe it to your future self -- and whoever is actually going to use this system -- to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I think there's just one important question. Will your program break if it somehow winds up with a duplicate UUID in the database? If the answer to that is yes, then you should be applying `unique=True`.

using `db_index=True` is more a matter of opinion. I'd say sure, go for it. It sounds like you're planning on using the field as an alternative to the id field. Indexing it shouldn't hurt anything much and would likely be helpful.